# how do i find out if tensorflow uses the gpu under windows and python 3.6?

Tags: tensorflow

how do i find out if tensorflow uses the gpu?
when I check the GPU in the task manager it says that it is 1% full. I find that a little bit, but I do not know whether the display may also be incorrect for the information.
I find the calculation too fast for only CPU, but actually too slow for GPU ...

is installed
tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu with version 1.15

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will confirm that tensorflow using GPU or CPU

```
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

Comment: ok there is everything with CPU: 0, can someone please help me step by step how I can activate the GPU?

Comment: @Metatron, If I have answered your question, can you please accept it and up vote it. Thanks